# Random plant growing in AeroGarden

Tags: identification, mint

[image]Started growing out of my mint container for my AeroGarden! Certainly isn’t mint but curious to know what it is. Has round leaves that grow in a circular pattern near the top and the leaves feel slightly rubbery

Answer (score 1):

I think that's [purslane](http://bodynutrition.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/purslane.png), an annual succulent weed. As you can see from the link, it's also edible. Do NOT let it set seed, though

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!